# get directory with absolute path in phonegap

Tags: cordova, path, absolute, getdirectories

I want to write a file or get a directory from absolute path in Phonegap, in 'File' API of PhoneGap has written

> getDirectory
>
> Creates or looks up an existing directory. An error results if the app attempts to:
>
> create a directory whose immediate parent does not yet exist.
> Parameters:
>
> path: The path to the directory to be looked up or created. Either an absolute path, or a >relative path from this DirectoryEntry. (DOMString)

But when a execute with absolute path , call back error function with error.code = 5
I tried with only directory, success.

Can you explain for me about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether your absolute path has // uri prepended. So your code will look like

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("//" + yourpath, onSuccess, onFail);
```

by prepending to the URI // it looks in the correct path.